# What is the difference between $L^1$ and $\mathcal L^1$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, harmonic-analysis

I am confused between definitions from my text book and this website. This is how I see them defined now:

$\mathcal  L^1({\mathbb{T}})= $ {$F:\mathbb{T}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}: F$ measurable and $\int_{\mathbb{T}}|F(\zeta)|d\lambda < \infty $}

$L^1({\mathbb{T}})$ is the quotient vector space $\mathcal  L^1({\mathbb{T}})$/{$F\in \mathcal L^1({\mathbb{T}}) : \|F\|_1=0 $}

And they both have the same norm $\|F\|_1 = \int_{\mathbb{T}}|F(\zeta)|d\lambda$

Initially, I found definitions for $L^1$ which were indentical to $\mathcal  L^1$. This may have been a problem of notation.

Comment: The point is that this function is not a norm in $\mathcal{L}$ because $||f||=0\to f=0$ don't works

Comment: Rudin defines $L^1(X)$ as a space of measurable functions, not equivalence classes

Comment: 1. Sometimes people use $\mathcal{L}^1$ to refer to the quotient space and don't really reserve notation for the space before quotienting. Conversely, sometimes people use $L^1$ to refer to the space before quotienting. I usually see the convention you stated here though. 2. The rationale for taking the quotient in the first place is to create a space that is actually normed. The "norm" on $\mathcal{L}^1$ in your notation is a seminorm.

Comment: 3. People are often imprecise about whether they are working with functions vs. equivalence classes, and there is good reason for this, so try to avoid being too nitpicky about the distinction.

Comment: Two quick questions:

Can I alternatively define $L^1({\mathbb{T}})= $ {$F:\mathbb{T}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}: F$ measurable, $\int_{\mathbb{T}}|F(\zeta)|d\lambda < \infty $, $\|F\|_1\ne0$}$ ?$

Is it true then that $L^1\subset \mathcal L^1$  $?$

Comment: As stated, yes, but this would be highly incompatible with established convention.

Comment: @rick196 the both definitions of $L^1$ are highly incompatible as both sets contains different kind of objects. That is equivalent classes vs functions. And your second definition excludes a zero.

Comment: @Ian is mistaken about your alternate definition being acceptable. While user251257 is being "too nitpicky" about it having equivalence classes vs functions, the absense of the $0$ function is much more crucial, preventing it from being a vector space. Adding $0$ explicitly will not fix this, because if $F, G \in L^1$ by your definition, then it is quite possible for $F - G$ to have measure $0$, and therefore not be in $L^1$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I really just meant that you *can* define things however you please as long as you stay consistent. But it would be a huge break from established convention for either $\mathcal{L}^1$ or $L^1$ to be defined such that they are not at least be vector spaces.